# Segmention fault: 11 in Python (Mac)

Tags: python, macos, segmentation-fault

I am trying to Code a Music Player in Python. I'm using MacOS 11.7.1 BigSur.
The Code itself works, but every time i select a song from the filedialog other than the song played before, i become the Error "Segmentation fault: 11". I then have to restart the script and select the same file as before to get it working.

I already searched up the internet and tryed to Max the Stack Size, but the Error is still coming up. Here's my Code:

```
import time
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from pygame import mixer
from tinytag import TinyTag
from PIL import Image
from threading import Thread
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import math
import os
import io

# Constant Variables
IMAGE_PATH = "cover.png"
IMAGE_SIZE = 128, 128

# Supported Filetypes
FILETYPES = (
    ('Audio Files', '*.mp3 *.ogg'),
    ('ogg Files', '*.ogg'),
    ("mp3 Files", "*.mp3"),
    ("All Files", "*.*")
)

# Asks the User to Select a File
filename = askopenfilename(
    title='Select a file...',
    filetypes=FILETYPES,
)

if filename == "":
    raise ValueError("Nothing Selected")

sg.theme("SystemDefaultForReal")

# Get Tags
tag = TinyTag.get(filename, image=True)
if tag.get_image() == None:
    pass
else:
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(tag.get_image()))
    image.thumbnail(IMAGE_SIZE)
    image.save(IMAGE_PATH)

# Time Variables
seconds = 0
minutes = 0
csec = 0
cmin = 0
paused = False
end = False

# Set Duration
for n in range(math.trunc(tag.duration)):
    seconds += 1
    if seconds == 60:
        seconds = 0
        minutes += 1

# Gui
layout = [
    [sg.Image(IMAGE_PATH)],
    [sg.Text(tag.title)],
    [sg.Text(tag.artist)],
    [sg.Text(tag.album)],
    [sg.ProgressBar(max_value=math.trunc(tag.duration), orientation='h', size=(20, 20), key='progress')],
    [sg.Text("-", key="pos")],
    [sg.Button("Pause", key="pause"),sg.Button("Go to"), sg.Button("Stop")]
]

window = sg.Window("Media Player", layout, element_justification="c")


# Position Manager
def count(start_pos):
    global pos, paused, end, csec, cmin
    if start_pos == "":
        pos = 0
    else:
        pos = int(start_pos)
    while True:
        if not paused:
            time.sleep(1)
            pos += 1
            _sec = pos
            csec = pos
            cmin = math.trunc(pos / 60)
            while True:
                _sec -= 60
                if _sec < 0:
                    break
                else:
                    csec = _sec
            if str(pos).endswith("0"):
                try:
                    mixer.music.rewind()
                    mixer.music.set_pos(pos)
                except:
                    pass
            if csec == seconds and cmin == minutes:
                end = True
        if end:
            break


# Play Music
mixer.init()
mixer.music.load(filename)
mixer.music.play()
media = Thread(target=count, name="Position Manger", args=(str(mixer.music.get_pos())[:-3],))
media.start()


# Goto function
def goto():
    global pos
    layout = [
        [sg.Text("Enter the Position (in Seconds):"), sg.InputText(0)],
        [sg.Button("Set")]
    ]

    window = sg.Window("Go to", layout)

    event, values = window.read()
    if event == "Set":
        mixer.music.play(0, float(values[0]))
        pos = int(values[0])
    window.close()


# Main Loop
while True:
    if end:
        break
    event, values = window.read(timeout=0)
    if event == "pause":
        if paused == True:
            mixer.music.unpause()
            paused = False
            window["pause"].update("Pause")
        else:
            mixer.music.pause()
            paused = True
            window["pause"].update("Resume")
    if event == "Stop" or sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        end = True
    elif event == "Go to":
        goto()
    window["pos"].update(f"{str(cmin)}:{str(csec)}/{str(minutes)}:{str(seconds)}")
    window["progress"].update(pos)
window.close()
mixer.music.unload()
os.remove(IMAGE_PATH)
```

How can i prevent this error from happen?
Thanks.

Comment: A seg fault in a Python script indicates a bug in the python interpreter or one of the libraries you import. It's not a problem in your script. Try narrowing things down so you can figure out which library is failing, then report it to them.